# How do I get a Gradle property in a Scala test?

Tags: scala, gradle, build.gradle, scalatest

I have this in my `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`:

```
com.my.path=/path/to/stuff
```

I have this in a Scala test:

```
class MyTest extends FunSuite {
    val path = sys.props.getOrElse("com.my.path", throw new RuntimeException("nope!"))
```

The test always throws an exception because `com.my.path` isn't in `sys.props`.

I tried prefixing the property in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` with `systemProp.` as suggested [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_system_properties), but it made no difference.

I also tried adding this to my build.gradle:

```
test {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

I forget where I read that, but it causes the test runner to fail with a "No tests found" error.

I'm running the test with IntelliJ FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any required properties must be passed to the test explicitly.
see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html

you pass gradle properties

```
test {
// set a system property for the test JVM(s)
  systemProperty 'some.prop', some.prop
}
```

Comment: You got me part way there. I updated the line in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` to `systemProp.com.my.path=/path/to/stuff` and used `systemProperty 'com.my.path', System.getProperty('com.my.path')` in `build.gradle` and it worked.